# A better way to swap two primary key values and circumvent a ORA-00001: unique constraint violated?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Goal:**
Swap the primary keys of two records without encountering an ORA-00001: unique constraint violated.  The solution that 'works' (further below) is just a silly hack.  Is there a feature/technique to defer constraint enforcement until the transaction is committed?
*As far as motivation* - a legacy application that uses this data has a design flaw and relies on the IDs order and values - the request is to swap the PK values as follows:

```
BEFORE: 
388    English
389    French

AFTER:
389    English
388    French
```

**What doesn't Work:**

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
      SET id = 388
    WHERE id = 389;

   UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
      SET id = 389
    WHERE id = 388;
END;
```

**Hack/Solution that 'works'**

```
DECLARE
  V_MAGIC_NUMBER   NUMBER := 9999999;
BEGIN
  UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
     SET id = 388 + V_MAGIC_NUMBER
   WHERE id = 389;

  UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
     SET id = 389 + V_MAGIC_NUMBER
   WHERE id = 388;

  UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
     SET id = id - V_MAGIC_NUMBER
   WHERE id = 389 + V_MAGIC_NUMBER;

  UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
     SET id = id - V_MAGIC_NUMBER
   WHERE id = 388 + V_MAGIC_NUMBER;

END;
```

**Table Definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
(
  ID             NUMBER(10)                     NOT NULL,
  LANGUAGE_NAME  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)              NOT NULL
)
```

**PK/UNIQUE INDEX:**

```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SL_PK ON SPOKEN_LANGUAGES    (ID)
```

Comment: What about simply dropping the index, performing the update and then rebuilding the index?

Comment: @BobC  This was definitely a suggestion that came up - it seemed the application developers were reluctant to adopt that strategy.  I also suggested we refactor the schema and/or application to support what it is they are trying to accomplish; rather than trying to 'fix it' as is.

Comment: Is this a one time fix, or some sort of regular maintenance? If it was one off, that I don't see a big problem with drop and rebuild the index. Having said that, @a_hourse came up with the right answer anyway. But as you say, and application the relies on that ordering is likely to run into other issues later...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do it in a single statement:

```
UPDATE SPOKEN_LANGUAGES
   SET id = case when id = 388 then 389 else 388 end
WHERE id in (388,389);
```

Comment: Hi @a-horse-with-no-name I have similar situation, with https://stackoverflow.com/q/60288050/1410223 but, some variable registers.
Can you help me please?